# Azure Data Factory Managed Airflow integration with Purview to get Lineage

Tags: azure, airflow, azure-data-factory, azure-purview

I am trying to use Azure Data Factory managed Airflow for my use cases. I am trying to use Azure Purview as data governance tool and want to use airflow to emit lineage to it.
I am trying to follow the Microsoft Document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/how-to-lineage-airflow). However, what i am stuck at is after i create event hub how do i configure the .yml file as Azure does it for me and i have no access to it. I am also not able to create the OPENLINEAGE_URL correctly pointing to Eventhub and it is throwing me 401(assuming i am not providing SAS correctly). This is the URL i am providing:
https://{event-hub-namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{event-hub}/messages

Answer (score 0):

i am also on the same process but have not reached the expected result yet.

Regarding the configuration of the .yml file there is a suggestion at the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1405026/azure-data-factory-managed-airflow-integration-wit

mentioning the following:

Did you try to create a new Variable and provide the YML contents?

1. Create a new variable.
2. In the "Key" field, enter "openlineage_config_yaml".
3. In the "Value" field, enter the contents of your .yml file.
4. Click on the "Save" button to save the variable.
5. Restart the Airflow scheduler to apply the changes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - i read through the airflow codebase on github. This variable name doesn't seem to be referenced in codebase